# Using computed properties with criteria query

Tags: java, database, mongodb, criteria

I have a mongodb collection. The documents have two fields called rtd ( number of days, int value) and timestamp (long value). I need to get all the documents satisfy this condition using Criteria query

if a document is x

currentTimestamp - x.timestamp converted to days < x.rtd

```
try {
            return mongoTemplate.find(query(criteria), PredictiveEntity.class).stream().filter(predictiveEntity ->
                    predictiveEntity.getRtd() >= TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(Instant.now().toEpochMilli() - predictiveEntity.getTimestamp(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            ).collect(Collectors.toList());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query can get you the expected output:

```
db.predictiveentry.find({
    $expr:{
        $lt:[
            {
                $toInt:{
                    $divide:[
                        {
                            $subtract:[new Date().getTime(), "$timestamp"]
                        },
                        86400000
                    ]
                }
            },
            "$rtd"
        ]
    }
})
```

**Since $expr is still not supported in Criteria, we need to follow a different route i.e parse the BSON query directly.**

```
Query query = new BasicQuery("{ $expr:{ $lt:[ { $toInt:{ $divide:[ { $subtract:[new Date().getTime(), '$timestamp'] }, 86400000 ] } }, '$rtd' ] } }");
return mongoTemplate.find(query, PredictiveEntity.class).stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
```